# Is there a way to update parent from unknown child's props or state change?

Tags: reactjs

Let's see we have a parent, which can have unknown number of children of unknown components. In my specific example, I have a dropdown menu with absolute position because of dnd list-order change. And I have a parent which is the provider of this dnd feature. I have an useEffect on the parent, which calls a function at every update, which sets the styles of the children, and the parent as well. Here's how it's looking like:

```
const SortDrag = ({ children, onChange, onEnd }) => {

    const sortDragContainer = useRef();

    const setStyles = () => {
        let top = 0;

        const { children, style } = sortDragContainer.current;

        [ ...children ].forEach(child => {

            const { offsetHeight: height } = child;

            child.style.transform = `translateY(${top}px)`;

            top += height;
        });

        style.height = `${top}px`;
    };

    const Elements = children.map((child, i) => {
        const { id } = child.props || child;

        return (
            <SortDragElement id={id} order={i} key={id}>
                {child}
            </SortDragElement>
        );
    }).sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (onChange) sortDragContainer.current.onChange = onChange;
        if (onEnd) sortDragContainer.current.onEnd = onEnd;
        if (reverse) sortDragContainer.current.reverse = reverse;
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => { setStyles(); });

    return (
        <div
            className="sort-drag-container"
            ref={sortDragContainer}
        >
            {Elements}
        </div>
    );
};

export default SortDrag;
```

I have event listeners in a separate file to handle the dnd feature, but it's not related to this problem, just don't want this to cause confusion.

What I'd like to update the parent component every time a change happens in one of it's children.

Comment: I've done something similar with [sticky events](https://www.slightedgecoder.com/2019/08/24/react-sticky-event-with-intersection-observer/) (<- shameless plug) where I had unknown children but had to be notified of changes. Basically I had a provider on the parent, and child component dispatched actions. In your case, `SortDragElement` can dispatch an action notifying the parent, and you can provide additional layer, (in my blog, `StickyRoot` would match your `SortDrag` component, meaning, you might need another parent component)